# Formatting numbers in datatable child row

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm sure this is an easy one for someone who knows, but I'm new to datatables and JS/JQ. So how can I format a string like this +d.price+ to output with commas?

Thanks in advance!

Angel

Comment: Can you please add your DataTables Code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way that I use to format Dates in my DataTable projects. You can use the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) plugin along with the [column render](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) advanced initialization option that DataTables offers.

In the column initialization for whichever column you want to format the date, use the following render function:

```
             render: function(data, type, row) {
               if (type === "sort" || type === "type") {
                 return data;
               }
               return moment(data).format("MM,DD,YYYY");
             }
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
    [ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
    [ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
    [ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
    [ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
    [ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
    [ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
    [ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
    [ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ],
    [ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
    [ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ],
    [ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ],
    [ "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500" ],
    [ "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000" ],
    [ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ],
    [ "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000" ],
    [ "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000" ],
    [ "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450" ],
    [ "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sydney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600" ],
    [ "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575" ],
    [ "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650" ],
    [ "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850" ],
    [ "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000" ],
    [ "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000" ],
    [ "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sydney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400" ],
    [ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500" ],
    [ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000" ],
    [ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
    [ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050" ],
    [ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ]
];
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date",
             render: function(data, type, row) {
               if (type === "sort" || type === "type") {
                 return data;
               }
               return moment(data).format("MM,DD,YYYY");
             }
            },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```